# Lebesgue integral of a bounded random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given a random variable $X$, if we take a **measurable** and **bounded** function $f(X)$ then can we say that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable wrt a probability measure on $\mathbb R$?
In Real Analyses book by Rudin(1976) (pg315) the above is stated with the additional condition that the measure is finite. But a probability measure is always finite right? so we don't need to require that.

Now, the doubt that I have is why for some rv the $f(X)$ is not Lebesgue integrable (like the Cauchy case)? What I think is because usually $f$ is **not bounded** and non-integrability has nothing to do with the measurability or the fact that the probability measure is infinite.

So, my final question is weather is safe to say that if $f(X)$ is bounded and measurable then the Lebesgue integral $\int_{\mathbb R}f(X) \, dP$ is always defined? is that right?

Any references or hints are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded then $f(X)$ will be Lebesgue-integrable even if $X$ is not.  For example, if $X$ has a Cauchy distribution, then $\cos X$ has an expected value.

The reason is that bounded measurable functions on spaces of finite measure are integrable.  The random variable $X$ is a measurable function on a probability space, whose total measure is $1$.  The composition of two measurable functions is measurable, and if $f$ is bounded then so is $f(X)$.  The random variable $f(X)$ is also a measurable function on a probability space with total measure $1$.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to spoil the party but to declare that $f(X)$ is (or is not) Lebesgue integrable is absurd and confuses the source set of $f(X)$ (aka some probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$) and its target space (often $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$). Lebesgue measure is a measure on the latter but, except in the rare cases when $\Omega$ itself is $\mathbb R$ or a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ and $F$ the Borel sigma-algebra, not on the former.

Comment: @Did : I was understanding the term "Lebesgue integrable" to mean the integral of its absolute value is finite, not that it is integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Ah, ok. This makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.